# How to get Symfony Bundle content into a website (existing template)

Tags: symfony, twig, bundle

I'm not that familar with Symfony and Twig yet. So, how do I solve this:

I've got a base App in Symfony, which has a frontend with static templates (a website).
Now, if I want to add a custom Bundle which should add some content into the main page (the App's default frontend), how do I do that?

The Bundle already is installed, but I don't know how to do it in best practice. Do I use a controller? But there will be rendered a view from this controller - that's confusing me. Or do I need global variables in Twig, create something like generators to add values to the variables? Or is there another way?

In short:
My Bundle should bring additional content into an existing App (website).

EDIT
The Bundle also has some own routes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got it:

I need to create a template inside the App, didn't set the template path to Bundle templates and just include the Bundle templates:

```
// App template in app/templates/website.html.twig
{% block content %}
    {% include '@Bundle/view/foobar.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

// Bundle template in Bundle/view/foobar.html.twig'
{{ form... }}
{{ something }}
```

The Bundle controller renders the variables into it's templates.

Is it best practice?